# What is the best way to do nothing here, where I am using a consumer widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-signin

I am trying to write keep the override part to do nothing since I don't want to implement anything. How would I do it with a consumer widget.

I know in stateful widget it is something like this:

`_MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();`

How can I do same for consumer widget below:

```
  const SignInWithGoogleButton({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  void signInWithGoogle(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    ref.read(authControllerProvider).signInWithGoogle();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    // TODO: implement build
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
```

Comment: You can just implement a class instead of a widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to do anything within your `build` method, you can just return a [`SizedBox.shrink()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SizedBox/SizedBox.shrink.html) widget:

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox.shrink();
  }
}
```